# variables from a JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift

i am a beginner with swift an Progrmamming i need values from the JSON it looks Like this...i don't understand this JSON..:-( :

```
{

"nextUpdate":300,
"subscriptions":["speedon","roamLikeHome","tns"],
"title":"",
"hasOffers":true,
"passName":"Ihr Telekom Datentarif",
"passStage":1,
"validityPeriod":2,
"initialVolume":6547308544,
"initialVolumeStr":"6,09 GB",
"usedVolume":2550134551,
"usedPercentage":39,
"usedVolumeStr":"2,37 GB",
"usedAt":1487480985000,
"remainingSeconds":833168,
"remainingTimeStr":"9 Tage 15 Std.",
"downSpeed":-1,
"downSpeedStr":"Max",
"upSpeed":-1,
"upSpeedStr":"Max",
"passType":103


}
```

i will get the usedVolume & usedPercentage to a variable!

my code :

```
    var volume: [String] = []
    var percent: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url=URL(string:"http://pass.telekom.de/api/service/generic/v1/status/.json")
        do {
            let allData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = data["??"] {........
```

How do i get it in the variable volume, percent..

thanks from your help..!

Comment: `data` is a plain old Swift dictionary. Use it like any other dictionary. You know what keys you want the values for. Just access those keys.

Comment: You can use a popular library to help you deal with JSON, called [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate question, you really, really shouldn't be accessing the remote data as you are. Your app will block due to the remote data access. There are proper ways to access remote data and what you are doing is not it. But that's a separate issue you can fix next.

Comment: You should cast to `as? [String : Any]` instead of `as? [String : AnyObject]` in Swift 3.x

Comment: @Heisenberg could  you trying with my answer . if you get any issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
    var usedVolume:Int?
    var usedPercent:Int?

    let url = URL(string:"http://pass.telekom.de/api/service/generic/v1/status/.json")

    do {

        let allData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allData, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
        if let uv = json["usedVolume"] as? Int {
            usedVolume = uv
        }

        if let up = json["usedPercentage"] as? Int {
            usedPercent = up
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: What does this add to the other question? And it has all of the same problems as the other answer.

Comment: from question I understand that he is new to swift so I just corrected.The answer is liitle different to show how to use variable to store data.

Comment: The values for the keys in question are not strings. And never load remote data on the main thread.

Comment: Yes I got your point but the question is only how to get these values from json.

Comment: Right. But if you are going to post an answer, post a helpful, correct answer.

Comment: hi, with your code i become this error ..Failed to load: The file “status” couldn’t be opened.

Comment: You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

Comment: I am getting nothing when I tried to paste http://pass.telekom.de/api/service/generic/v1/status/.json on brouser even on postman

Comment: usedVolume and usedVolume are Integers not Strings